# Python - Knight's tour recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I realize that there're many implementations of [Knight's tour problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-set-1-the-knights-tour-problem/) suggested across webs, without jumping to those suggested solutions (most in Java, I'm not proficient in Java), I managed to implement one myself using Python. It works and returns some results.

**Description**

> A knight's tour is a sequence of moves of a knight on a chessboard such that the knight visits every square only once. If the knight ends on a square that is one knight's move from the beginning square (so that it could tour the board again immediately, following the same path), the tour is closed, otherwise it is open.

For example:

```
board = Board(4,4)
a = list(dfs_search([0,0], tuple()))
```

Outputs:

```
# a[0]

([0, 0], [2, 1], [3, 3], [0, 2], [1, 0], [3, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [3, 2], [1, 1], [3, 0], [2, 3], [0, 3], [2, 2], [0, 1], [1, 3])
```

Most of the outputs are correct, which seems that the recursive function is actually working. The last few vertex, transit from `[1,1]` to `[3,0]` is problematic. I've spent hours debugging trying to resolve it, but failed. As the last resort, I bring the question here, hoping anyone could shed some light to my implementation.

This is my implemntaion of Knight's tour problem using recusive functions.

```
def dfs_search(start, path):
    if not path:
        path = (start,)
    if len(path) == board.goal:
        yield path

    for next_cell in board.avaiable_moves(start):
        if next_cell not in path:
            path += (next_cell,)
            yield from dfs_search(next_cell, path)

class Board(object):
    def __init__(self, width, length):
        self.width = width
        self.length = length
        self.goal = width * length


    def is_legit_move(self, cell):
        row, col = cell
        return (row >= 0 and row <= self.width-1) and (col >=0 and col <= self.length-1)


    def avaiable_moves(self, cell):
        ret = []
        r, c = cell
        tmp = [[r+1, c-2], [r+2, c-1], [r+2, c+1], [r+1, c+2],\
               [r-1, c-2], [r-2, c-1], [r-2, c+1], [r-1, c+2]]
        for elem in tmp:
            if self.is_legit_move(elem):
                ret.append(elem)
        return ret
```

Comment: _I've spent hours debugging trying to resolve it, but failed._ So the code is not working as expected, which makes the question off-topic here.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I hadn't even noticed that... , but this is one of those cases where it seems to work. If we do not focus on the bug, but on the code itself, is it on-topic then?

Comment: @Ludisposed Unfortunately it's in black and white that they only want us to fix the bug - "I've spent hours debugging trying to resolve it, but failed. As the last resort, I bring the question here, hoping anyone could shed some light to my implementation. " And so violates the "To the best of my knowledge, does the code work as intended?" reason.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've tried StackOverflow before coming here, which wasn't very helpful, 2 mins 2 downvotes and suggested to close... Just wondered, where is appropriate to put this kind of question? @Peilonrayz

Comment: @Logan stackoverflow seems appropriate. Maybe the wording wasn't clear enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much to say about this, only a few small nitpicks.

1. `self.height` might be a better name, (width and height) make more sense to me. But this might be subjective.
2. At `is_ligit_move()` you could use, `elem in range()`, because `range` is special. See [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178772/codefights-pipes-game/178794#178794) excellent description by [@Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/98493/graipher) for more details.
3. At `available_moves` you could use list comprehension instead of the `res` variable

So your res would be this:

`return [elem for elem in possible_moves if self.is_legit_move(elem)]`

It does the same but looks a little cleaner. See [PEP202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) for more information.

---

Overall I think you have crafted a nice piece of code!

Answer (score 1):

Few more observations:

- there is a typo: `avaiable_moves` -> `available_moves`
- `available_moves()` might become a generator:

  ```
  def available_moves(self, cell):
      r, c = cell
      tmp = [[r+1, c-2], [r+2, c-1], [r+2, c+1], [r+1, c+2],
             [r-1, c-2], [r-2, c-1], [r-2, c+1], [r-1, c+2]]
      for elem in tmp:
          if self.is_legit_move(elem):
              yield elem
  ```
- to take it further, that `tmp` variable could be replaced with a bit more robust cell combination generation mechanism:

  ```
  def available_moves(self, cell):
      row, column = cell
      for offset_row, offset_column in product((1, -1), (2, -2)):
          for new_cell in [(row + offset_row, column + offset_column),
                           (column + offset_column, row + offset_row)]:
              if self.is_legit_move(new_cell):
                  yield new_cell
  ```

  Don't forget to add the import statement `from itertools import product`.

  Note that `product((1, -1), (2, -2))` part should be pre-calculated and be configured as a constant, no reason to re-do it every time `available_moves()` is called.
- I would also question the `if next_cell not in path` part. Since `path` is a tuple, checking for `next_cell` presence/absence would take \$O(n)\$ time-complexity wise, where `n` for a chess board is 64 which for 8x8 board is probably not a problem. But, for a general board, it would possibly make more sense to sacrifice some space and introduce a `seen` set of visited cell (presence check would then take constant time) and use it to check if you've already visited a set or not

Comment: Great addidtions, but why not `in range()`? Instead of `x <= row <= y`. I liked the new `available_moves` much smoother

Comment: @Ludisposed ah, yeah, `in range()` would be a better option, removed that part from the answer. Thanks.